# "mini chess" recursion doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, recursion

I have a "mini chess" game, where the horse can move the same as regular chess game, I need to find the shortest path from the horse `H` to the king `K`.

I need to write a **recursive** function.
the function signature should be `public static int minPath(char[][] minChess,int i,int j)`

In my solution I marked every place that the horse stepped with `X` and therefore the horse can't step twice on same place and I think that this is the cause of my wrong solution.

Here is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] minChess={{'0','0','K','0'},
                           {'0','0','0','0'},
                           {'0','0','0','0'},
                           {'H','0','0','0'}};

        System.out.println(minPath(minChess,3,0));
    }

    public static int minPath(char[][] minChess,int i,int j)
    {
        return minPath(minChess,i,j,0);
    }
    
    public static int minPath(char[][] minChess,int i,int j,int count)
    {
        if(!isValidLocation(minChess,i,j))
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        
        if(minChess[i][j]=='K'){
            return count;
        }
        if(minChess[i][j]=='X'){
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
            
        minChess[i][j]='X';
       //all direction the hourse can move
        int dir1=minPath(minChess,i-1,j-2,count+1);     
        int dir2=minPath(minChess,i-2,j-1,count+1); 
        int dir3=minPath(minChess,i-2,j+1,count+1);     
        int dir4=minPath(minChess,i-1,j+2,count+1);     
        int dir5=minPath(minChess,i+1,j+2,count+1);     
        int dir6=minPath(minChess,i+2,j+1,count+1);         
        int dir7=minPath(minChess,i+1,j-2,count+1);     
        int dir8=minPath(minChess,i+2,j-1,count+1);
        
        
        return Math.min(dir1,Math.min(dir2, Math.min(dir3, Math.min(dir4, Math.min(dir5, Math.min(dir6, Math.min(dir7, dir8)))))));
        
    }
    public static boolean isValidLocation(char[][] a,int i,int j)
    {
        return i>=0&&j>=0&&i<a.length&&j<a[0].length;
    }
```

The output is: 5 but it should be 3.

can't see how to complete the solution

Comment: Simply changing the order fixed it... [Demo](https://ideone.com/YCAAnS) not sure why though

Comment: @Lino if `K` placed in `[1,2]` your sulotion gives `6`, but it should give `4`

Comment: Your strategy is a depth-first search. When you first find a non-optimal path, it will be filled with `X`, so you can't find the optimal path that shares a cell with it.

Comment: @saka1029 Right, but can't find how to solve this

Comment: What about adding `minChess[i][j] = '0';` after `int dir8=minPath(minChess,i+2,j-1,count+1);`?

Comment: @saka1029 looks like it work! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the line

minChess[i][j] = ״0״

below the recursive calls.

That will clean the marked cells

Answer (score 0):

This method calculates all shortest distances for board size (height x width) starts with (startX, startY)

```
static final int[][] DIRECTIONS = {
    {-2, -1}, {-2, 1}, {-1, -2}, {-1, 2},
    {1, -2}, {1, 2}, {2, -1}, {2, 1}};

static int[][] shortestDistances(int height, int width, int startX, int startY) {
    int[][] board = new int[height][width];
    for (int[] row : board)
        Arrays.fill(row, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    new Object() {
        void set(int x, int y, int distance) {
            if (x < 0 || x >= height || y < 0 || y >= width)
                return;
            if (distance >= board[x][y])
                return;
            board[x][y] = distance;
            for (int[] direction : DIRECTIONS)
                set(x + direction[0], y + direction[1], distance + 1);
        }
    }.set(startX, startY, 0);
    return board;
}
```

a sample run (4 x 4 board, starts with (3, 0))

```
int[][] distances = shortestDistances(4, 4, 3, 0);
for (int[] row : distances)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
```

result

```
[5, 2, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 4, 3]
[3, 4, 1, 2]
[0, 3, 2, 5]
```

If the king were at (0, 2), the distance would be 3.

Comment: the method must be recursive as I mentioned in port (it's in bold).loops are not allowed

Answer (score 0):

I wrote almost the same solution as you, sharing my code with details

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    char[][] minChess = 
        {
                {'0','0','0','0'},
                {'0','0','0','0'},
                {'0','0','K','0'},
                {'H','0','0','0'}
        };
    
    System.out.println(minPath(minChess, 3, 0)); // 1, at least one move from horse ('H') to king ('K')
    
    char[][] minChess1 = 
        {
                {'0','0','0','0'},
                {'0','0','K','0'},
                {'0','0','0','0'},
                {'H','0','0','0'}
        };
    System.out.println(minPath(minChess1, 3, 0)); // 4, at least four moves from horse ('H') to king ('K')
    
    char[][] minChess2 = 
        {
                {'0','0','K','0'},
                {'0','0','0','0'},
                {'0','0','0','0'},
                {'H','0','0','0'}
        };
    System.out.println(minPath(minChess2, 3, 0)); // 3, at least three moves from horse ('H') to king ('K')
}

public static int minPath(char[][] minChess, int i, int j)
{
    return minPath(minChess, i, j, 0);
}

private static int minPath(char[][] minChess, int row, int col, int moves)
{
    if (row < 0 || row >= minChess.length|| col < 0 || col >= minChess[row].length) // boundaries
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    
    if (minChess[row][col] == '*') // if we have been here before, this step is to avoid infinite recursive calls
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    
    if (minChess[row][col] == 'K') // if we can threat the king
        return moves;
    
    char temp = minChess[row][col];
    minChess[row][col] = '*';
    
    int r1 = minPath(minChess, row - 2, col + 1, moves + 1); // move 2 up and 1 to the right
    int r2 = minPath(minChess, row - 2, col - 1, moves + 1); // move 2 up and 1 to the left
    int r3 = minPath(minChess, row - 1, col + 2, moves + 1); // move 1 up and 2 to the right
    int r4 = minPath(minChess, row - 1, col - 2, moves + 1); // move 1 up and 2 to the left
    int r5 = minPath(minChess, row + 2, col - 1, moves + 1); // move 2 down and 1 to the left
    int r6 = minPath(minChess, row + 2, col + 1, moves + 1); // move 2 down and 1 to the right
    int r7 = minPath(minChess, row + 1, col + 2, moves + 1); // move 1 down and 2 to the right
    int r8 = minPath(minChess, row + 1, col - 2, moves + 1); // move 1 down and 2 to the left
    
    minChess[row][col] = temp; // revert changes
    
    return Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(r1, r2), Math.min(r3, r4)), Math.min(Math.min(r5, r6), Math.min(r7, r8)));
}
```